# How to install ArcGIS Code Assist in Aptana 3?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, aptana

I have downloaded Aptana and **[ArcGIS Code Assist](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/api_codeassist.html)** but I don't know how to "DRAG" the vsDOC into Aptana.

> Aptana 3 Installation Instructions
>   Download the zip file that contains the VSDoc file for the version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript you are using.
>   Drag the VSDoc file into your Aptana project.

I drag it into my project workspace and it only shows the .js file content. How do I actually use it?

Comment: For me your question is not clear. Check out following link which may be helpful for you (Code Assist Plugins web help) https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/api_codeassist.html

Comment: +1 http://balumypersonalgis.blogspot.in/2012/05/best-ides-for-arcgis-api-for-javascript.html

Comment: I am not sure but "drag" means after creating the project in Aptana you need to put the file in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You should use only Aptana 2 to get code assist and the higher version is not compatible. Please check this link http://joelmccune.com/2012/03/22/an-ide-with-code-assist-for-the-arcgis-javascript-api/

Answer (score 0):

Download the file from here: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/api_codeassist.html and it to your project like you would any other file.